# Remove leading zeroes from select double quoted field(s) within unix flat file (awk, sed)

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a flat file (txt/csv) with a single header and many records. I want to use awk/sed/unix tools to strip leading zeros from fields 3 and 5 only on the records (could be one or many leading zeroes). Looked at several solutions, but most don't seem to account for the values being double quoted. Example:

```
"ACCOUNT","REAL","022000046977525","REAL","00000220000488","ONLINE",......
```

Tried some awk and sed, with printf, regex, etc. Am I missing something already published? ideas? thanks.

Desired output:

```
"ACCOUNT","REAL","22000046977525","REAL","220000488","ONLINE",......
```

Comment: @Jesse_b - not on the header. added for clarity on that one, could use something like NR >1 if in awk, for example. thanks

Comment: Can any of your quoted fields contain commas or escaped quotes or newlines? If the answer is yes then it becomes a harder problem and if the answer is no then - why are they quoted?

Comment: Ed Morton - they could, but Jesse_b's awk solution targets action only to be taken on fields 3 and 5, which will always be wholly numeric. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{OFS=","; sub(/"0+/, "\"", $3); sub(/"0+/, "\"", $5)}1'
```

Shouldn't be an issue unless your header actually has leading zeros but if needed you could do:

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1{OFS=","; sub(/^"0+/, "\"", $3); sub(/^"0+/, "\"", $5)}1'
```

This will replace the `"` and all leading zeros in fields 3 and 5 with just a quote.

Comment: Great solution and approach on the two fields in question. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html), given a CSV file with headers

```
$ cat file.csv
"000001","000002","000003","000004","000005","000006","000007"
"ACCOUNT","REAL","022000046977525","REAL","00000220000488","ONLINE",......
```

(silly field names chosen to demonstrate that leading zeros in the header are not affected) then

```
$ mlr --csv --ofmt '%.0f' --quote-all put '$000003=$000003; $000005=$000005' file.csv
"000001","000002","000003","000004","000005","000006","000007"
"ACCOUNT","REAL","22000046977525","REAL","220000488","ONLINE","......"
```

---

Alternatively, with `csvformat` (from python csvkit) and `numfmt` (from GNU Coreutils):

```
$ csvformat file.csv | numfmt -d, --header --field 3,5 --format '%.0f' | csvformat -U2
"000001","000002","000003","000004","000005","000006","000007"
"ACCOUNT","REAL","22000046977525","REAL","220000488","ONLINE","......"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -re '
   s/","/\n/4;s//\n/2
   s/\n0*([0-9])/","\1/g
' file.csv
```

Assuming that all the fields are quoted.

Mark the third and fifth fields by a newline and remove any leading zeros. In case all are zeros, it will preserve last rather than make the field vanish.